# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta el ajax desde mis achivos de directorio?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php
    include('class.Conexion.php');

    if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
        $db = new Conexion();
        $filtro = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['buscar']);
        $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '%$filtro%'; ");

        if ($db->rows($sql) > 0) {
            while ($auto = $db->recorrer($sql) ) {
                echo $auto['email'],' y el nombre es ',$auto['nombre'] ,' y el precio es ', $auto['password'], '</br>';
            }
        }else{

        }

    }else{
        echo "No se a encontrado Resultado";

    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Buscador</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('document').ready(function () {
            $('#buscar').autocomplete({
                source : ['ajaxhp','hoal','465']
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
            echo '</br>si existe la variable buscar';
        }
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <label>Buscar: </label><input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar">
        <input type="submit" value="buscar">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 errores:

1. Debes incluir primero el `script` de `jQuery` y a continuación `jQuery UI`
2. Te falta incluir el archivo `CSS` para `jQuery UI`

Ejemplo:

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
  $('#buscar').autocomplete({
      source : ['ajaxhp','hoal','465']
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <label>Buscar: </label><input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar">
    <input type="submit" value="buscar">
</form>
```

Comment: El tema <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/*base*/jquery-ui.css"> es depende al que selecion cuando la descargue

Comment: @Gamez, Si es una pregunta, la respuesta es si, es recomendable que la versión del `CSS` para `jQuery UI` coincida con la del `JS`

Comment: me funciona gracias

Comment: tengo una duda y es porque no lo llama desde mi directorio, editare la pregunta

Comment: @Gamez, no entiendo la duda, intenta explicarte mejor. ¿A que te refieres con "_porque no lo llama desde mi directorio_"?

Answer (score 0):

Tu sintaxis esta mal, o al menos no la he utilizado así puedes probar algo así:

```
       $('#buscar').autocomplete({
            minLength:2,
            source : miautocomplete.php?variable=10,
            select:function(){
            //Aquí se hace algo cuando es seleccionado     
          }
        });
```